# Is there a XML Schema (XSD) for SDF?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

First of all, thanks to everyone who supports Gazebo and OSRF.

I was wondering, is there a XML Schema (XSD) for the SDF format?

Thanks,

Will

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5085/is-there-a-xml-schema-(xsd)-for-sdf?/) by [Mentok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/581/mentok/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the schema for sdformat here: http://sdformat.org/schemas/root.xsd

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/142/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 136 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There currently is no schema. However, it's now on my radar to get done.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kunal Tyagi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/986/kunal-tyagi/) on 2014-10-17**:
Any updates on that @nkoenig?